# I am getting a circular dependency error on power Bi when I put a calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
    KPI Value_3 Months = 
    VAR current_actual = 
                            IF (ISBLANK ([Actual]), FALSE, TRUE)
    VAR current_target = 
                        IF (ISBLANK([Target]), FALSE, TRUE)
    RETURN
            IF(
            current_target && current_target,
            DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM(BI_SC_Perf_Measurement_Lvl2[Actual]),DATESINPERIOD(BI_SC_Perf_Measurement_Lvl2[Reporting_Period],LASTDATE(BI_SC_Perf_Measurement_Lvl2[Reporting_Period]),-3,MONTH))/3 , 
            CALCULATE(SUM(BI_SC_Perf_Measurement_Lvl2[Target]),DATESINPERIOD(BI_SC_Perf_Measurement_Lvl2[Reporting_Period],LASTDATE(BI_SC_Perf_Measurement_Lvl2[Reporting_Period]),-3,MONTH))/3), 
        BLANK ()
        )
```

---

and I am creating another column with the following code:

```
KPI Status_3 Months = 
            VAR _bottomthreshold2 = .55
            VAR __middlethreshold2 = .75
            VAR _topthreshold2 = 1
        
RETURN
        SWITCH(
                TRUE (),
                [KPI Value_3 Months] < _bottomthreshold2, -1,
                [KPI Value_3 Months] >= _bottomthreshold2
                    && [KPI Value_3 Months] <= __middlethreshold2, 0,
                [KPI Value_3 Months] > __middlethreshold2
                    && [KPI Value_3 Months] < _topthreshold2, 1,
                [KPI Value_3 Months] >= _topthreshold2, 2
        )
```

I am getting this error "A circular dependency was detected: BI_SC_Perf_Measurement_Lvl2[KPI Value_3 Months], BI_SC_Perf_Measurement_Lvl2[KPI Color_3 Months], BI_SC_Perf_Measurement_Lvl2[KPI Status_3 Months], BI_SC_Perf_Measurement_Lvl2[KPI Value_3 Months]."

Comment: Please share some data, data model etc..  so people have a chance to test and react to your post faster.

Comment: Would you mind including a screenshot of the relevant tables in your data model so that we can see the relationships?